# Find finite-history recurrence from full-history recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236000/solve-differential-equation-fz-e-2-fz-e2) I asked for a closed-form solution to this functional differential equation: 
\begin{align*}
f'(z) &= e^{-2} (f(z/e))^2 \\
f(0) &= 1.
\end{align*}

It doesn't look like there is one, but I'm interested in another question about $f$.
The Maclaurin coefficients $f_n = [z^n]f(z)$ satisfy

\begin{align*}
f_n &= \frac{e^{-n-1}}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f_{j-1} f_{n-j}, \qquad n > 0, \\
f_0 &= 1.
\end{align*}

This is a full-history recurrence relation for $f_n$;
that is, all previous terms are involved.
Is there a finite-history recurrence?

A sufficient condition is that $f(z)$ is holonomic, but that's not clear to me.